# How to extend an array or append a value to array field on Django ORM's Queryset Update? [Postgresql]

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an ArrayField to store Colors for a given Dish object in a Schema and the dishes also have a category

```
class Dish(models.Model):
   colors = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=16))
   category = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Let's say I have 15 Dish objects, out of which 13 belong to the "Cookware" category and the remaining 2 belong to "Modware"

Now I want to append a color to the existing list of colors for a given category in a single update query method (Which has to append my new color to all the array fields of matching Dishes, 13 items in my case)

Following are the ways that I have tried to perform this operation and ended up having errors

- `Dish.objects.filter(category="Cookware").update(colors=F("colors")+"red")`
- `Dish.objects.filter(category="Cookware").update(colors=F("colors")+["red"])`

Following is the error message I am facing when I am trying with the above two queries
`No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`

The following obviously doesn't work as **apppend** will return None
`Dish.objects.filter(category="Cookware").update(colors=F("colors").append("red"))`

PS: Using Django(3.2), Django ORM, Postgres ***ArrayField*** from  ***django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField***

Thanks in advance for spending your time to help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using native `django` field it's impossible as https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26355 is open still. To do it you can use `django-postgres-extensions` lib.

```py
from django_postgres_extensions.models.fields import ArrayField

class Dish(models.Model):
   colors = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=16))
   category = models.CharField(max_length=32)

# ...
from django_postgres_extensions.models.functions import ArrayAppend

Dish.objects.filter(category="Cookware").update(colors=ArrayAppend('colors', 'red'))
```

Comment: Hey @Glech thanks for the solution, however there is a small fix that needs to be done to make `django-postgres-extensions` work in latest Django Versions (>=3)
The following requirement should be installed `pip install django-utils-six`